# Thrift call gives "unknown result"

Tags: thrift

I have a Thrift connection between a remote server & a web service.. thrift interface is compiled using 0.9.0 thrift compiler. When I make thrift calls to the remote server, it executes successfully in the remote, but in the client side - i see the following error:

> org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: PredictScoresNoPersist failed: unknown result

I checked the web, and checked all the solutions mentioned -- like mismatch in the thrift jars etc.. no luck yet. Please help.

Just a little background, this is a single-threaded REST client.

Comment: The obvious reason is, that the call to the PredictScoresNoPersist() method failed with an exception, that is not listed in the service IDL (which is not so hard, because in that particular cxase, there is just plain none: https://github.com/sgdheeban/te/blob/master/ITargetingEngine.thrift). The not-so-obvious question is, what causes the server to fail. Sounds not like a Thrift problem to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exception is clearly thrown at the client, thus the message response seems correctly transported:

```
public Map<String,Double> recv_PredictScoresNoPersist() throws org.apache.thrift.TException
    {
      PredictScoresNoPersist_result result = new PredictScoresNoPersist_result();
      receiveBase(result, "PredictScoresNoPersist");
      if (result.isSetSuccess()) {
        return result.success;
      }
      throw new org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException(org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.MISSING_RESULT, "PredictScoresNoPersist failed: unknown result");
    }
```

The only two possible reasons I see are:

- the server throws an (uncaught) exception
- you try to return a `null` result, which is illegal with Thrift.

Comment: +1 ^^ : A null reference was being passed. Just found the bug. Thanks for the quick help.